# How to detect an inventory environment in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have the requirement to skip some steps in my scripts when I run a deployment against `production`.

When a playbook is started, it always requires an environment (`-i` option), so there would be information I could query to distinguish which steps to take.
This leads me to ask: 
**How can I query the environment I am running a playbook in?**

As an alternative, I could provide an extra variable as a parameter like `-e "env=prod"`. But this would be redundant, since I have specified the environment already with `-i`...

Another option would be to set up a group `environment`, put all hosts of this environment in there, and define a `group_var` called `env: prod`. But putting all hosts in this group is overkill.

Bottom line: can I query the environment? Is there another option I'm not considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Magic Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html) in the Ansible documentation:

> Also available, `inventory_dir` is the pathname of the directory holding Ansible’s inventory host file, `inventory_file` is the pathname and the filename pointing to the Ansible’s inventory host file.

Use string manipulation to extract the information you want from the above variable (e.g., the last segment from the path).

Answer (score 0):

A filter exists to extract the last part of a pathname/filename :

[managing-file-names-and-path-names](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-file-names-and-path-names)

So you can use `inventory_file | basename`